# Rails 3.1 + postgresql database - sql syntax error for SELECT ... WHERE ... IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails 3.1 setup with postgres 8.4. Here are my gem versions:

> ```
> activerecord (3.1.3)
>   activemodel (= 3.1.3)
>   activesupport (= 3.1.3)
>   arel (~> 2.2.1)
>   tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
> activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.1)
> activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (1.2.1)
>   activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.2.1)
>   jdbc-postgres (~> 9.0.0)
> ```

Now, when I do this query in my controller:

`@topics = Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ["\"ForumID\" in ?, @forum_ids]`

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'abc123'"
Position: 62: SELECT "topic".* FROM "topic"  WHERE ("ForumID" in 'abc123','1234')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 314ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'abc123'"
Position: 62: SELECT "topic".* FROM "topic"  WHERE ("ForumID" in 'abc123','1234')):
```

I think the problem is where the parenthesis is being placed in the SQL statement. It should be after **in** instead of being before "ForumID".

`SELECT "topic".* FROM "topic"  WHERE "ForumID" in ('abc123','1234')` works perfectly, so is this a bug in the postgresql adapter, or am I doing something wrong in my query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that you are missing parentheses inside the query. So this one should work:

```
@topics = Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ["ForumID in (?)", @forum_ids])
```

As you are on Rails 3.1, it's better to use:

```
@topis = Topic.where("ForumID in (?)", @forum_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to have

```
@topics = Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ["\"ForumID\" in ?", @forum_ids]
```

Notice the closing `"` in the conditions.

As a side note, you can do this in Rails 3 with

```
 @topics = Topic.where("\"ForumID\" in ?", @forum_ids)
```

And possibly even (check the syntax)

```
@topics = Topic.where(:ForumID => @forum_ids)
```

Comment: i did have the closing ". i didn't copy and paste, so i missed it when i was typing up the question. good catch though.